# How to make a start with Microsoft C++

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I have recently started learning C++ and I thought I have covered learning all basics. Now I have a job to do over some legacy C++ code written over microsoft.net VC++.

It is not a gui application, it is a service. It has all the typedefs like LPCTSTR, DWORD etc. Is there any comprehensive guide where I can see the usage of each of these?

Comment: I don't understand why this isn't a real question... "beginner" implies that he doesn't know what these are or what their purpose is. Why is asking for a place to obtain their definitions wrong?

Comment: I voted to close because this question is far too broad to be answered.  He basically is asking for the spec for c++

Comment: @Woot4Moo not hardly. He's asking an intelligent question: where do I find documentation as to the purpose of these types that the standard language does not define? What is so "broad" about that? He didn't ask you for a precise definition for each typedef in MFC.

Comment: @San: I thoroughly agree. The question clearly is a real question, because it has a real answer, which is the MSDN page that describes them.

Comment: @San fair enough, perhaps there should be an option to close questions that could take 2 seconds to google.  Not saying that I have never been guilty of this, but it would be handy

Comment: @Woot4Moo:  Take pity on the poor beginner.  They are trying to learn C++ while using managed C++; I cannot think of a worse way to start off.

Comment: @Billy: Why did this get tagged C++/CLI?  There's nothing in the question that has anything to do with managed code.

Comment: @Ben: 1. It was tagged with .NET initially (where C++ does not run). 2. The string "written over microsoft.net VC++" gets parsed by me as "written as Microsoft's implementation of C++ on the .NET platform" -- that is, C++/CLI.

Comment: @Billy: That's a fair reading, but equally valid is "the C++ compiler that comes with Visual Studio .NET" which could refer to either the native or managed compiler.  And the types mentioned are 100% native and quite unlikely to be used in C++/CLI code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa505945.aspx

That should cover most (if not all) of the defines/typedefs with good explanations.

EDIT:
And just like San Jacinto mentioned, MSDN is very good place to get information about Windows development.

Comment: Thank you... I was in real hurry.. sorry if this question is not a real question.. but now it is easy to search for others c++ beginners once this is on SO! Stackoverflow allows me to get instant replies. Thanks Henry.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to learn more about C++ in general and don't mind paying a little bit, I recommend Deitel & Deitel.

[Here](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=deitel+c%2B%2B+how+to+program&hl=en&prmd=ivns&resnum=5&biw=1366&bih=643&um=1&ie=UTF-8&cid=13031541644518472703&sa=X&ei=KYwbTYWNHsGclgeC-LSyDA&ved=0CE0Q8gIwAA#) is a link to a Google page which lists various places you can find the same book I used in my C++ class in school.  It's easy to understand, comes with loads and loads of examples and sample problems, and is just an overall great book, especially for beginners like me.